# Visual Studio debugging, see/not see debug.writelines

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Is there any mechanism where you `Debug.WriteLine(someinfo)` while you are debugging a project and mark off some checkbox where this debug.writeline(someinfo) doesn't get called if I don't want to. I want to see the debug info on small data, but on big data I can just turn it off without me commenting out all the debug.writelines. Is there such thing is `#DEBUG`/preprocessor flags that I can use in Visual Studio? I'm still in the "Debug" context when I want to see and not see the debug.writelines depending on some kind of flag?

Comment: You mean, other than just not looking at the Output window?

Comment: I want to basically comment out all my Debug.WriteLines when I don't want to instead of manually commenting out them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new Build Configuration (base on Debug, and named `DEBUG_NO_TRACE`, for example).

Menu 
Build => ConfigurationManager

In Active Solution Configuration, Select new , Copy settings from Debug

Then create a new preprocessor flag `#DEBUG_NO_TRACE` in you project properties (Build tab).

And put `#IF DEBUG_NO_TRACE` where you want a difference.

And chosse that build configuration when you want to.

But there's maybe a more elegant solution...

Comment: Perhaps he could also create a simple wrapper method that calls `Debug.WriteLine` only if the preprocessor flag is defined.  He would of course have to go through his existing calls and route it to that new method instead.

Comment: For sure. But creating the new Build and Preprocessor flag would be same as in my answer, or did I miss something ?

Answer (score 3):

Available options:

- Right-click the Output window and untick the "Program output" option
- Project + Properties, Build tab, untick the "Define DEBUG constant" option and rebuild
- Add `Trace.Listeners.Clear();` to your Main method.